# Should the Angular Module be a Empty JavaScript Module?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I'm now learning [Angular 7](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c). I'm currently clear about the bootstrapping design in Angular and the metadata object usage marking angular components and modules. However, I've still not seen an example or a case where angular module is not an empty class.

So, I'm currently wonder that:

- Angular Module is only designed statically to configure and organize related things together?
- Involving Dynamic Logic code in an Angular Module, maybe written in constructor of the module class, is not a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the main difference is that Angular components, modules and services use decorators from the angular package.

E.g. `@Component()` does this:

```
 * Component decorator allows you to mark a class as an Angular component and provide additional
 * metadata that determines how the component should be processed, instantiated and used at
 * runtime.
```

This is straight from the source code which you can look up.

The things you pass into this is also quite angular-specific. Other than that, no there should not be a big difference.

If you interface with a component which needs initialization, you should not use the JS constructor. It will execute slightly earlier than `ngOnInit` and could cause problems since this is how angular works.

If you write custom modules then you can of course just do things conventionally.

A way to initialize modules is the [`forRoot` convention:](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot)
Here you basically create a singleton with a given configuration:
(taken from the link)

**src/app/core/user.service.ts (constructor)**

```
constructor(@Optional() config: UserServiceConfig) {
  if (config) { this._userName = config.userName; }
}
```

**src/app/core/core.module.ts (forRoot)**

```
static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: CoreModule,
    providers: [
      {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
    ]
  };
}
```

**src/app/app.module.ts (imports)**

```
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
/* . . . */
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ContactModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot({userName: 'Miss Marple'}),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
/* . . . */
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: So I actually wonder that if there is such a thing like ngOnInit provided or available for an Angular Module, rather than angular component.

Comment: There is. Itt is called the forRoot convention. Many modules do it and here is the doc: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot

will update the answer with that